# How does java comparator work internally?

Tags: java, comparator

```
class Checker implements Comparator<Player> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
        if (p1.score == p2.score) {
            return p1.name.compareTo(p2.name);
        } else {
            return p2.score - p1.score;
        }
    }
}
```

how does p2.score - p1.score make it descend
while p1.score - p2.score makes is ascend

how does a positive or negative integer or zero return
sort the objects? whats going on internally

please help thanks

Comment: I like to think of it this way: `a<b` can also be written as `a-b<0`. In other words when `a<b` `compare(a,b)` should return value which is `<0`. When `a==b` then `compare(a,b)` should return `0`. When `a>b` `compare(a,b)` should return value `>0`. Based on that, sorting algorithms (which by default try to order "from smallest to largest") make decision if currently compared pair of elements `a` and `b` should swapped their places or not.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html For the mathematically inclined, the relation that defines the imposed ordering that a given comparator c imposes on a given set of objects S is:

       {(x, y) such that c.compare(x, y) <= 0}.
 
The quotient for this total order is:
       {(x, y) such that c.compare(x, y) == 0}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`Comparator`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html):

> A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some collection of objects. ...

And from [`Comparator:compare`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)):

> ...
>
> Returns:
>
> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Thus, the `Comparator` only defines the order. It is up to the sorting algorithm to use this information and actually sort the data structure. If we take a look how, e.g., [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) work, we see that these algorithms only need to know whether some element `a` is smaller, equal or larger than `b`, which is the information that a `Comparator` provides (by returning a value `< 0`, `= 0` or `> 0`).

Now let us explain how `a - b` makes it sort in ascending order (lets give this `Comparator` the name `asc`), while `b - a` makes it sort in decreasing order ((lets give this `Comparator` the name `desc`): We have to look at three different cases for the two `Comparator`s.

First, suppose that `a > b`. Then

- `a - b > 0`, thus `a` is "larger" than `b` according to `asc`
- `b - a < 0`, thus `a` is "smaller" than `b` according to `desc`

Next, suppose that `a < b`. Then

- `a - b < 0`  thus `a` is "smaller" than `b` according to `asc`
- `b - a > 0`, thus `a` is "larger" than `b` according to `desc`

Finally, suppose that `a == b`. Then `a - b == b - a == 0` and the elements are "equal" according to both `Comparator`s.

Comment: how do I know if a is less than or greater than b. does the first object in my array get compared first with the second?

Comment: As I said: please look at some well-known sorting algorithms like Quicksort and Merge Sort. Everywhere, where those algorithms use `<`, `==` or `>`, the `Comparator::compare`-method is called and its return-value is evaluated (`< 0` for `<`, `== 0` for `==` and `> 0` for `>`).